# separate php error logs for each Apache vhosts

Tags: php, apache-2.4, logging

Is it possible to separate php error logs for each Apache vhost ?
I am running Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) and PHP 5.4.45 (cli)
For example i tried php_value and PHPINIDir in my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
....
PHPINIDir /usr/local/zend/var/log/my_host_php_error.log
....
</VirtualHost>
```

same vhost with php_value

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
....
php_value error_log /usr/local/zend/var/log/my_host_php_error.log
....
</VirtualHost>
```

after that i got these messages:

> Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>
> Invalid command 'PHPINIDir', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Is it possible to do that via Apache config ?

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with below in your apache virtualhost config.

**php_value error_log  /usr/local/zend/var/log/my_host_php_error.log**

and

Just open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load this file and check if below line is uncommented.

LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

if yes, uncomment it and restart apache.

Comment: Got the same apache message.

Comment: @Darius S open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load this file and check if below line is uncommented. 


LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

if yes, uncomment it and restart apache.

Comment: after a2enmod php5.load, got 
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

php5.load content without comment:
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so

Comment: run below command and see if module is properly installed or not: 

 dpkg -l |grep libapache2-mod-php5  also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/520033/apache-php5-problem-after-12-04-3-to-14-04-i-do-release-upgrade-server

Comment: @SachinSingh You should add all of this to your answer so it is complete